# Sending URL encoded string in POST request using node.js

Tags: node.js, api, postman, stormpath

I am having difficulty sending a url encoded string to the Stormpath `/oauth/token` API endpoint. The string is meant to look like this:

```
 grant_type=password&username=<username>&password=<password>
```

Using Postman I was successful in hitting the endpoint and retrieving the data I want by providing a string similar to the one above in the request body by selecting the raw / text option. But when I generate the code snippet it looks like this:

```
var request = require("request");

var options = { method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://<My DNS label>.apps.stormpath.io/oauth/token',
  headers: 
   { 'postman-token': '<token>',
     'cache-control': 'no-cache',
     'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
     host: '<My DNS label>.apps.stormpath.io',
     accept: 'application/json' },
  form: false };

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);

  console.log(body);
});
```

Where did that string go? I would like some help in understanding the disconnect between knowing I sent a url encoded string to the API endpoint using Postman and not seeing it in the code generated by Postman. Because now I don't know how to reproduce a successful call to the endpoint in my actual app.

To me it seems like I should simply provide a `body` to the request, but the response comes out to be `{"error":"invalid_request","message":"invalid_request"}`. I have also tried appending the url encoded string to the url but that returns a 404 error.

I'm just now getting back into using an API and am not very experienced doing so.

Comment: That looks like a query string/query parameters. If that's the case, just append that string to the `url` after a `?`, like this: `http://example.com/page?key1=value&key2=value`

Comment: This seems like a Postman bug. I'd try asking about/reporting it via one of the avenues mentioned in the [Postman App Support README](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/blob/support/README.md).

Comment: @qxz I've tried appending the correctly formatted string to the `url` value and that returns me a 404 error. But good looking out I did try that before I asked the question. @Jordan I will check it out, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form data needs to be posted as an object, here is an example:

`request.post('http://service.com/upload', {form:{key:'value'}})`

Taken from this documentation:

https://github.com/request/request#forms

Hope this helps!

Comment: See that's what makes the most sense to me but as you can see the Postman code snippet doesn't have the url encoded string in any form, weird huh?

Comment: Thanks @robertjd for the help. It turned out I wasn't sending a properly formulated string in the first place and that's where the errors were coming from.